# How to Show Tool tips in Pie Chart in Asp.mvc asp x c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I created chart dynamically in controller  like this

```
var chart = new Chart();    
      var returnStream = new MemoryStream();
            chart.ImageType = ChartImageType.Png;
            chart.SaveImage(returnStream);
            returnStream.Position = 0;
            return new FileStreamResult(returnStream, "image/png");  
//finally iam returning image to view and binding to image
```

#### is there any way to returning instead of image

#### because i need tool tips on charts

Answer (score 0):

You will have to combine two actions (one for the image, one for the map), and use the ImageMap RenderType for the map :

see "Chart Image Rendering" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456682.aspx

and "Interactivity" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456772.aspx

Comment: Nope. I guess this can be of some help : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/297677/Using-ASP-Net-Charting-with-Image-Map-in-MVC